# Is there way to avoid DNS timeout when calling getnameinfo

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2012

i have question about faster/different way of searching local network.

Here is some code that i made for searching through local network, code work but am not sure is that good approach to fasten the search. I read on MSDN that i should use threading for this beacuze getnameinfo does not support timeout control.

Question is, is this good way to fasten the search or there is better approach?

Any hints would be appreciated!!

Thank you :))

```
// link with ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

void check_ip_address(char* adradr)

{

// Declare and initialize variables
WSADATA wsaData = {0};
int iResult = 0;

DWORD dwRetval;

struct sockaddr_in saGNI;
char hostname[NI_MAXHOST];
char servInfo[NI_MAXSERV];
u_short port = 27015;

std::string str;
std::stringstream ss;
std::ofstream log_file;
std::ostream_iterator<std::string> os(log_file, "\n");
std::vector<std::string> vec;


// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    std::cout<< "WSAStartup failed: %d\n" << iResult;
}


// Set up sockaddr_in structure which is passed
// to the getnameinfo function
saGNI.sin_family = AF_INET;
saGNI.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(adradr);
saGNI.sin_port = htons(port);


// Call getnameinfo
dwRetval = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &saGNI,
                       sizeof (struct sockaddr),
                       hostname,
                       NI_MAXHOST, servInfo, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NUMERICSERV);


if (dwRetval != 0) {
    std::cout<< "getnameinfo failed with error # %ld\n" << WSAGetLastError();
} 
else {
    std::cout<< adradr << " --> getnameinfo returned hostname = " << hostname << std::endl;
}


    log_file.open("log.txt", std::ios::app);
    ss << adradr << " --> getnameinfo returned hostname = " << hostname;
    str = ss.str();
    vec.push_back(str);
    copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), os);
    log_file.close();
}


int main()
{
    std::ofstream log_file;
    char* charr_address = "192.168.";
    log_file.open("log.txt");
    log_file.close();

for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 255; ++j)
    { 
        //function that concat/deconcat address(nothing special)
        charr_address = concat_deconcat_address(charr_address, i, j);

        std::thread t1(check_ip_address, charr_address);
        t1.detach();
    }
}

std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(15));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Detatching threads usually isn't a good idea.

Comment: Any suggestion what should i do?

Comment: Did you compare performance with non-threaded code?

Comment: Yes, every time i call getnameinfo and if there is no one on that address it takes few seconds(to long to search through hole local network). With this code i spawn threads and imidietly detach them, main thread continue runing and when it hits end i put him to sleep for longest time it takes for detached thread to write into log_file(15sec).

Comment: That's not a good idea as you may overload the system with waaaay too many threads. Better to use a thread pool, and re-use finished threads. That is why many popular network scanners have maximum number of threads parameter per say.